# How to give access to guest user to a particular directory in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, guest-session

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed. I want to give access of a specific folder of my administrator account to a guest user. How can i do that? eg. take folder as ~/Videos.
So that if anybody log-in as a guest user can watch at least movies. All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guest users are denied access per design to home directories of ordinary users. It's controlled via App Armor.

My recommendation, if you have a bunch of files that you want your guest users to access, is that you copy (or move) them to somewhere outside of `/home`, e.g. `/var/local/videos`.

Comment: Is that a new characteristic of Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: @Charo: No, the guest session feature has worked that way all since it was introduced, first in the gdm-guest-session package, and later in lightdm. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html